# Sencha Touch c.blur is not a function

Tags: sencha-touch

Does everyone know why this error occurs in Sencha Touch 2.3.0?

```
TypeError: c.blur is not a function
```

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're either using sencha-touch-all.js, or you're trying to debug a "production" build from Sencha Cmd.

If it's the former, use sencha-touch-all-debug.js instead.

If you're using Cmd, run the app in development mode.

In both cases you'll get a more accurate idea of what the error is. You should also use Google Chrome and set "Pause on Exceptions" in your Sources tab so that you can see what is throwing the error.